# Number theory: For every $n,m$ with $1 \leq n < m$, find $a,b$ such that $a^n|b^m$ but $a∤b$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Let $1≤n <m$ be two fixed integer.

(a) Prove that if $a \mid b$, then $a^n \mid b^m$.

(b) Prove that $ \exists$ positive integers $a,b$ where $a \nmid b$ but $a^n \mid b^m$

I can get the answer for part (a), but I dont have any ideas about part (b). Can someone give me some hints for this question? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2):

$(a)$ We have $a \mid b \implies a^n \mid b^n$. Since $n<m$, we also have $b^n \mid b^m$. This gives us $a^n \mid b^m$.

$(b)$ Just set $a=x^m$ and $b=x^n$ for some positive integer $x>1$. We can clearly see that since $m>n$, $$ x^m>x^n \implies x^m \nmid x^n \implies a \nmid b$$
But we have $a^n=b^m=x^{mn}$ which clearly shows that $a^n \mid b^m$ since every number divides itself.

Comment: Thank you so much! 
And thank you for helping me to edit the question!

Comment: @Gloven My pleasure! I would suggest you learn some mathjax notation. One of the users has given you some links below your question as a comment. You could check those out.